# IIS ASP.NET 1.1 Application - Server Error Page - Abstraction from User

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-1.1, asp.net-1.1

Currently our application gets the following error page.

```
Server Error in '/' Application
```

This even in case of a custom errors set to RemoteOnly.

What is the HTTP Error Code of this error? This because, we can add it under Custom Errors on InetMgr and set it to a Custom Error Page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server errors get raised as 500's usually (Internal Server Error).